# Connecting web parts to metadata navigation in document library

Tags: 2010, web-part, document-library, managed-metadata

Is it possible to read from the metadata navigation in a document library so that the selected value(s) can be passed into another web-part (in this case a CoreResultsWebPart ).

The IsNodeSelected property on the **MetadataNavigationContext** class is reserved for internal use, what is the recommended approach? The metadata navigation does provide a query string in the URL (a very long and complex one) but i'm not sure about trying to de-code this either in case it changes in the next version.

I haven't been able to locate any documentation on how to work with the metadata navigation, any recommendations or links would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 1):

You will find samples of SharePoint 2010 managed metadata term or tag navigation web parts here:

Tree style term set navigation:

http://www.layer2.de/en/products/Pages/Tag-Navigation-Web-Part-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Flat glossary-style term set navigation:

http://www.layer2.de/en/products/Pages/Tag-Directory-Web-Part-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Both read the taxonomy structure in term store and provide flexible links to either, the search results (for term or tag ID) or to tag profile pages alternatively.

Thanks, Frank

Comment: Thanks Frank, but i'm trying to work with the built in metadata navigation, these are links to paid 3rd party web parts. Thanks anyway.